# Responsive website theme not working on iPhone.

Tags: html, css

I am currently in the process of editing a theme to be responsive for my website thats running Oxwall. The theme's responsive features currently work on computer browsers from what I have tested but I can get it to work on the iPhone. When loaded the website still stays wide and big.

Can any one help me with what part of the CSS seems to be holding my website wide on iphone browsers?

http://omol.org

Thanks, Jamie.

Comment: I've answered, but voted to close too as is this is very localised.

Comment: Jamie, welcome to SA and I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. For your future reference the usual practice on Stack Overflow is to select the correct answer which was posted first. Cheers, Billy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

See why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a meta viewport tag defined.

Here's an example of one but obviously you can configure them in a variety of ways:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Assuming you have your media queries set up correctly in your stylesheets then adding the meta viewport tag should get you going.

Comment: Upvote as it's right :)

Comment: Thanks @RyanMcDonough - just trying to teach the new guy some manners :p Gave your answer an upvote too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a meta viewport tag defined. Add this code to the head part of your file.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Avoid using maximum scale because it prevents visually impaired users to use your site.

Source: http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/